# Create a DOM Document from an Url

Tags: java, xml, url, dom

the url : http://www.evemarketeer.com/api/orders/10000043/30119/xml

I tried this

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
```

But isn't working, anyone got any idea to create a Document with an easy method ?

Thx

Comment: What does that mean it is not working? any errors?

Comment: Got no error, but the var doc is null.

Comment: Are you sure stream returning something?

Comment: Try it by yourself ^^ http://www.evemarketeer.com/api/orders/10000043/30119/xml

Comment: How are you determining that the `doc` variable is null? Are you simply printing it, or are you actually comparing it to null? If you're simply printing it, you're being fooled by the `toString()` implementation. There should be no way for the `parse()` method to return an actual null without throwing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me (returns 28 "row" elements)

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.evemarketeer.com/api/orders/10000043/30119/xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");
System.out.println(nodes.getLength() + " nodes found");
```